# PHP Variable Value For Pagination

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I'll paste my code here, it goes like if a person selects a category and then he lands to another page, now here the problem is because mysql_fetch_rows selects all the rows of all categories, so if there are 10 entries, 5 in each category and if i set to show 1 post per each page instead of showing 5 pages it shows 10 pages but after page 5 i get a php error. thank you n here's my code

```
$pagination_shoot = "SELECT id, po_title, po_category FROM tbl_posts WHERE po_category = '{$category}'";

$page_dump = mysql_query($pagination_shoot, $db_connect);

$no_rows = mysql_fetch_row($page_dump);

$numrows = $no_rows[0];

$rows_per_page = 1;

$lastpage = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);

$page = (int)$page;

if ($page > $lastpage) {
$page = $lastpage;
} // if

if ($page < 1) {
$page = 1;
} // if

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($page - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

//Run Post Query
$data_posts = "SELECT id, po_title, po_category FROM tbl_posts WHERE po_category = '{$category}' {$limit}"; //Post Query

$fetch_data_posts = mysql_query($data_posts, $db_connect);

while ($list_posts = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_data_posts))
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you are probably running a server with `register_globals` enabled. If you are, [turn it off](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: If i remove where condition script works well but the only problem is that it is not able to detect which category has what number of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think what you are trying to do is fetch the results for a specific page from that database while knowing how many results there are in total, so you can work out how many pages there will be. Here is the right way to do that using [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
// Populate these variables however you see fit (eg through $_GET)
$rows_per_page = 1;
$current_page = 1;

// -----------

// Make sure the page number is >= 1
$current_page = (int) $current_page;
if ($current_page < 1) $current_page = 1;

// Calculate values for LIMIT clause
$limitQty = (int) $rows_per_page;
$limitBase = ($current_page - 1) * $limitQty;


// Run the query
$query = "
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    `id`, `po_title`, `po_category`
  FROM `tbl_posts`
  WHERE `po_category` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($category, $db_connect)."'
  LIMIT $limitBase, $limitQty
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db_connect);

// Store the results in an array and free the MySQL resource
$data_posts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data_posts[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($result);

// Get the total number of rows
$query = "
  SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db_connect);
$numrows = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$total_rows = $numrows[0];
mysql_free_result($result);

// Calculate the total number of pages
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $rows_per_page);

if ($current_page > $total_pages) {
  // Handle a request that asked for a page which is greater than the total number of pages
  // You could display an error message, redirect to a page within range, or run another query
  // to fetch the rows for the last page.
}

// Now you can loop the data results and do whatever you want with them
foreach ($data_posts as $list_posts) {
  // ...
}
```